# Why does function composition work when applied to functions that take multiple arguments?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, idris

I think I understand how function application works when writing out the steps, but the type signature arithmetic doesn't add up in my head. Apologies for the long prelude (no pun intended).

To bring a specific example, this one is a slightly altered example from [Stefan Höck's Idris2 tutorial](https://github.com/stefan-hoeck/idris2-tutorial/blob/main/src/Tutorial/Functions1.md#higher-order-functions):

```
plusTwo : Integer -> Integer
plusTwo = (+2)

twice : (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer
twice f n = f (f n)
```

In the REPL(s):

```
> twice plusTwo 3
7

> (twice . twice) plusTwo 3
11
```

#### What I know

- functions both in Haskell and Idris are [curried and every function takes only one argument](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying)
- function composition is [implemented](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html#:%7E:text=As%20another%20example) as

  ```
  f . g = \x -> f (g x)
  ```
- function application is **left** associative
- arrows in type signatures are **right** associative

#### Writing out `(twice . twice) plusTwo 3`

The expression can be explicitly parenthesized as

```
((twice . twice) plusTwo) 3
```

which can be re-written as

```
       ------f-------- -n-
(twice (twice plusTwo)) 3
             |
             V
------f-------- (------f-------- -n-)
(twice plusTwo) ((twice plusTwo)  3 )
                 \------------------/
                          |||
                  plusTwo (plusTwo 3)
                          |||
                           7                 
\-----------------------------------/
              |||
         twice plusTwo 7
```

#### Seeming type signature mismatch

The function composition operator's type signature below shows that it takes one-argument functions,

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

but `twice` takes two arguments (i.e., `(t -> t) -> t -> t`), so this throws me off.

I guess the only way this works when the argument `x` of the returned lambda is itself a function. Could it be this simple?

```
        twice        .          twice
((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> a -> a) ->  ?

(---b---- -> --c---) -> (---a---- -> --b---) -> (a -> c)

? = (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

or, to put it another way, `twice . twice` takes a function with the signature `(a -> a) -> a` (where `a` here is `Integer`).

---

If the above stuff is correct, then I can figure out function compositions where the participating functions have differing input arguments (e.g., `twice . (+2)`).

Comment: Indeed, in Haskell all the functions take exactly one argument. We informally speak of an "n-ary" function when we have a function taking one argument returning a function taking another argument and returning a function taking another argument ... (n times). This is only a shortcut for humans, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's really all it is. It may make it easier to think about if you write the signature of `twice` as

```
twice :: (Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer)
```

As you know, this is equivalent thanks to currying. Seen this way, `twice` is a function of one argument, and composing it with `twice` again seems perfectly sensible.